# ColdFusion and .Net sessions

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, coldfusion, ws-security

Web applications commonly have a client-side and server-side, whereas in my particular scenario we have client-side, and two server-side technologies using web services to perform operations and make requests.

*Although not relevant to the underlying problem, the reason for this setup is simply due to the fact that our desktop-based applications use .Net whereas our web applications use ColdFusion and we've been slowly transitioning the server processes to .Net, using web services as a means of performing these operations, thereby undoubtedly making the switch to a full .Net solution much easier in the near future.*

**Problem**

The issue is when I call a .Net web service From ColdFusion, .Net doesn't seem to retain the session beyond the HTTP request.

However, if I call that same web service using Ajax with jQuery, the session is retained beyond a single HTTP request. (across all my pages)

The web service is registered in the `OnApplicationStart` function of the `Application.cfc` component in Cold Fusion. (Note: the SoapHeader implements **ws-security**)

```
<cfscript>
    objSoapHeader = XmlParse("<wsse:Security mustUnderstand=""true"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd""><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>MY_USERNAME</wsse:Username><wsse:Password>MY_PASSWORD</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>");
    Application.UserWebService = CreateObject("webservice","MY_URL/UserService.asmx?WSDL");
    addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.UserWebService,"","",objSoapHeader,true);
</cfscript>
```

When calling the same web service from jQuery, the header and body is structured as such:

```
var strSoapData = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Header><LanguageHeader xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><Locale>en-CA</Locale></LanguageHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body>" + strData + "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
```

In order to handle `ws-security` in .Net the following code is placed in the `web.config` file:

```
<webServices>
    <soapExtensionImporterTypes>
        <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Description.WseExtensionImporter, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </soapExtensionImporterTypes>
    <soapServerProtocolFactory type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocolFactory, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</webServices>
```

**Question**

After hours of research and trial and error, what next step can I even take in order to pin point the underlying issue as to why my session is being lost in .Net when calling a web service from Cold Fusion?

**EDIT**

After a little more research I believe that Cold Fusion is not retaining the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie, perhaps cookies all together. I'll attempt a cookie-less approach and update with my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution what as simple as enabling cookies on the web service.

```
Application.UserWebService.setMaintainSession(true);
```